# How do i send a message in telegram to someone from whom i only have a chat ID?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I only have a chat id number from someone and i have no other information, i have not been in contact with him in Telegram before.

How can i send a message to him only with the chat ID or get his username only with the chat ID.

I know the following link, where there is chat ID, takes me to the chat page with the person.

tg://openmessage?user_id="Chat ID Number"

But this link works when i have already contacted the person in question, or an in a group, or have spoken, or have her number.

What is it like when i have no information about the person in question and only have a chat ID?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You should as you said have encountered them in your dialogs or contacts or any mutual group.

There aren't any known methods to bypass this restriction.